# I can't delete my VPN interface on Windows 10 - it's stuck in "connecting" and busy

Tags: windows, vpn

I've been battling issues with VPN connectivity for the last day, and troubleshooting this has become a pain in the ass. I think I've finally gotten the solution figured out, but I can't even "reset" my VPN connection because it's stuck in the "Connecting" stage. If I try to delete the interface, Windows tells me that it's busy and I can't delete it while it's busy. I've tried disabling the interface in Device Manager, and Device Manager just freezes up.

The only way I've been able to do this in the past was to reboot the entire system, and I can't keep rebooting the system while I have so much work going on.

Is there another solution to forcibly remove an interface such as this VPN one? It's one of those WAN Miniport ones.

Comment: Have to do any of these operations while in Safe Mode?

Answer (score -1):

What about if you go to Control Panel>Network and Internet>Network Connections and delete/disable it there?

I've got several VPNs on mine that I end up using where I disable them there.

Also, is this a 3rd party software? Like Cisco or something? If so, it might have a service under Windows Services running where you can disable it there as well.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment).